# giving an uninitialized array values in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, list-initialization

My question is very basic, but I couldn't find anything about it.
I have an array of pointers. I want to assign it like this

```c
mat* quickAccessMatrices[6] = {&MAT_A,&MAT_B,&MAT_C,&MAT_D,&MAT_E,&MAT_F};
```

with MAT_A,MAT_B,...,MAT_F being variables of type mat, which is a structure defined elsewhere. this gives a warning when using -pedantic flag, saying

```
initializer element is not computable at load time
```

so I think it means I shouldn't do it.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```c
mat* quickAccessMatrices;
quickAccessMatrices = {&MAT_A,&MAT_B,&MAT_C,&MAT_D,&MAT_E,&MAT_F};
```

just without it giving an error?

Or do I just need to assign it values slot by slot?

By the way, since people were asking, here is how I define mat

```c
typedef struct mat {
        double matrix[4][4];
} mat;
```

I am well aware this isn't that good, but it is necessary in my case
To be clear, I know that I can use normal assignment after the definition, but I'm asking if there is a better way.

Comment: @IłyaBursov not an exact duplicate IMHO, just a typo.

Comment: I'm asking if there is a different way of doing this

Comment: How is `mat` declared?  How about the variables you're using in the initializer?

Comment: You are assigning an array to a pointer. What do you expect the result to be? Either you do it in the definition, or you need to do it at runtime later.

Comment: mat is a properly defined structure that works just as intended. I am not getting any errors, just warnings, and the code works fine besides them.

Comment: Don't describe the code, *show* the code.

Comment: Ok I added in the definition of mat

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Be sure to copy and paste enough code into your question to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration the declared variable is a scalar object

```
mat* quickAccessMatrices = {&MAT_A,&MAT_B,&MAT_C,&MAT_D,&MAT_E,&MAT_F};
```

but you are trying to initialize it with a braced list of several initializers as an array.

You could declare an array as

```
mat* quickAccessMatrices[] = {&MAT_A,&MAT_B,&MAT_C,&MAT_D,&MAT_E,&MAT_F};
```

Or you could declare a pointer of the type `mat **` and initialize it with a compound literal like

```
mat** quickAccessMatrices = ( mat *[] ) { &MAT_A,&MAT_B,&MAT_C,&MAT_D,&MAT_E,&MAT_F};
```

As for this warning

> initializer element is not computable at load time

when you may not initialize arrays in file scope with non-constant expressions. So declare the array or the pointer to the compound ;literal in a function for example in `main`.

Comment: I forgot to add the square brackets in the question, but I did add them in the code. the warning remains

Comment: @PlainXYZ See my appended answer.

Comment: I don't think I understand what "declare the array or the pointer to the compound; literal" I am already defining the array in main, and it still gives the error

Comment: @PlainXYZ You shall provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the error.

Comment: I'm currently trying to reproduce the issue on a smaller scale, I will need a minute

Comment: @PlainXYZ Maybe the error is relative to objects MAT_A and so on that also have an array as their data member and that are declared in file scope.

Comment: Yea, I think you're right. I'll just use the method mentioned in some other comments of assigning values after initialization.